# Incorporate dropdown and dialog together in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and need your help.
I have a dropdown and on selecting a value I am checking if selected value is not meeting a condition I need to prompt a dialog box to user if he wants to continue to go with the selection,if he selects yes then selected value to be saved in database.

On select and on selecting yes are two callback functions. My query is how to set the state for current selected value during OnSelect callback so that I can make it available within OnSelectYes also.

Comment: please provide minimal implementations in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into https://react-select.com/async

Will make it easier to make this select component that you want.